# Hibernate Update not working...using Spring framework

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

POJO:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "created_at")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date createdAt;

@Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "updated_at")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date updatedAt;
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class HomeController {
    @Autowired
    private NameDao nDao;

    @RequestMapping(value="/update/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getUpdate(@PathVariable int id, Model model){
        Stamp st = (Stamp) nDao.getById(id);
        model.addAttribute("s", st);
        return "update";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/update/{id}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postUpdate(@ModelAttribute Stamp s){
        nDao.updateName(s);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

Update.jsp:

```
<h1>Update Here...</h1>
    <form method = "post">
        <div>
            <label>Name: </label><input type="text" value="${s.name}" name="name">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

My only concern is using the createdAt and updatedAt for each entry. On using createdAt and updatedAt dateTime, the problem of updating arose. Update now working. Any solution to use dateTime for createdAt and updatedAt working with upadate operation. Insert option works fine here.

Answer (score 0):

Use @CreationTimestamp and @UpdateTimestamp instead of manually setting those values

Comment: do i have to assign variable in pojo for this technique...as @CreationTimestamp
    private Date createdAt = new Date(); ... what is your suggestion here...coz i have tried this as well...but same issue...while updating, it saves as the new record instead of updating it

Comment: you don't need to initiate it.
Just annotate the variable

Comment: "not-null property references a null or transient value : com.project.test.entity.Stamp.createdAt" error....my database schema is name = created_at, type = TIMESTAMP, Null = No, Defalut = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP....and for name = updated_at, type = TIMESTAMP, Null = Yes, Default = NULL, Extra = ON_UPDATE_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP....is any modification needed here...

Comment: what does your pojo (entity) look like after the change ?

Comment: nothing is changed...only i have replaced @Generated annotaion with CreationTimestamp and UpdateTimestamp annotations only...